# List of Authorisation errors with Firebase login

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-security

What I need is a complete list of FirebaseAuthentication codes for all the different login errors and also a list of all those errors. So far I have found some by trial and error but can't take the risk I have missed some.

I am using the Firebase simple login to log in with email/password, facebook, twitter and also anonymous logins. Obviously with this many login methods there are lots of ways the user can fail to login correctly (incorrect email format, didn't enter a password etc). Currently I am using this code:

```
... authenticateWithDictionary method

completion:^(NSError * error, id<PUser> user) {

    if (!error) {

        [self loginButtonPressed:Nil];
    }
    else {

        [UIView alertWithTitle:bErrorTitle withError:error];
    }
```

The only issue with this is I end my getting errors raised which read like this:

```
**(Error Code: EMAIL_TAKEN) The specified email address is already in use.**
```

This is fine to let me know what has gone wrong in testing but once the app goes live I will want individual messages to 
a) look tidier
b) let the user know why they have got this error

So far through trial and error I have figured out the following:

error code

```
-5      INVALID EMAIL - empty or incorrect format
-6      INVALID PASSWORD
-9      EMAIL TAKEN
```

Once I have a complete list I am going to use a switch statement to get them all being dealt with correctly

Does anyone know the comprehensive list of error codes and errors so that I can take them all into account without having to think through all the options which might mean I miss one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the full list of error codes from the Firebase website:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-full-error

Comment: There's also similar Objective-C documentation here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-full-error - also Firebase Simple Login has been deprecated in favor of the new Firebase v2 with built in authentication: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html

Comment: For Firebase 3 and above you can find the auth codes here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword

Answer (score 6):

You can find all firebase auth errors codes and explanations under `FIRAuthErrorCode` enum in `FirebaseAuth.framework`

```
/*
 Indicates a validation error with the custom token.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidCustomToken = 17000,

/*
 Indicates the service account and the API key belong to different projects.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeCustomTokenMismatch = 17002,

/*
 Indicates the IDP token or requestUri is invalid.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidCredential = 17004,

/*
 Indicates the user's account is disabled on the server.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeUserDisabled = 17005,

/*
 Indicates the administrator disabled sign in with the specified identity provider.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeOperationNotAllowed = 17006,

/*
 Indicates the email used to attempt a sign up is already in use.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse = 17007,

/*
 Indicates the email is invalid.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidEmail = 17008,

/*
 Indicates the user attempted sign in with a wrong password.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeWrongPassword = 17009,

/*
 Indicates that too many requests were made to a server method.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeTooManyRequests = 17010,

/*
 Indicates the user account was not found.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeUserNotFound = 17011,

/*
 Indicates account linking is required.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeAccountExistsWithDifferentCredential = 17012,

/*
 Same enum as @c FIRAuthErrorCodeAccountExistsWithDifferentCredential ,
    but with incorrect spelling. Only exists for backwards compatiblity.
 */
FIRAuthErrrorCodeAccountExistsWithDifferentCredential = 17012,

/*
 Indicates the user has attemped to change email or password more than 5 minutes after
    signing in.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeRequiresRecentLogin = 17014,

/*
 Indicates an attempt to link a provider to which the account is already linked.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeProviderAlreadyLinked = 17015,

/*
 Indicates an attempt to unlink a provider that is not linked.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeNoSuchProvider = 17016,

/*
 Indicates user's saved auth credential is invalid, the user needs to sign in again.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidUserToken = 17017,

/*
 Indicates a network error occurred (such as a timeout, interrupted connection, or
    unreachable host). These types of errors are often recoverable with a retry. The @c
    NSUnderlyingError field in the @c NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain the error
    encountered.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeNetworkError = 17020,

/*
 Indicates the saved token has expired, for example, the user may have changed account
    password on another device. The user needs to sign in again on the device that made this
    request.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeUserTokenExpired = 17021,

/*
 Indicates an invalid API key was supplied in the request.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidAPIKey = 17023,

/*
 Indicates that an attempt was made to reauthenticate with a user which is not the current
    user.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeUserMismatch = 17024,

/*
 Indicates an attempt to link with a credential that has already been linked with a
    different Firebase account
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeCredentialAlreadyInUse = 17025,

/*
 Indicates an attempt to set a password that is considered too weak.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeWeakPassword = 17026,

/*
 Indicates the App is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication with the
    provided API Key.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeAppNotAuthorized = 17028,

/*
 Indicates the OOB code is expired.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeExpiredActionCode = 17029,

/*
 Indicates the OOB code is invalid.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidActionCode = 17030,

/*
 Indicates that there are invalid parameters in the payload during a "send password reset
 *  email" attempt.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidMessagePayload = 17031,

/*
 Indicates that the sender email is invalid during a "send password reset email" attempt.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidSender = 17032,

/*
 Indicates that the recipient email is invalid.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInvalidRecipientEmail = 17033,

/*
 Indicates an error occurred while attempting to access the keychain.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeKeychainError = 17995,

/*
 Indicates an internal error occurred.
 */
FIRAuthErrorCodeInternalError = 17999,
```

Answer (score 3):

Localize Firebase error messages in PT-BR

https://gist.github.com/Albejr/a38cdeac247ef177986c99629680afb4

```
catchError(err => {
    const errorCode = err.code;
    let errorMessage = this.VerifyErroCode(errorCode);

    if (errorMessage == null) {
        errorMessage = err.message;
    }
    
    console.log(errorMessage);
})

VerifyErroCode(errorCode: string): string {
        // fonte: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth
        // fonte: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors?hl=pt-br
        switch (errorCode) {
            case 'auth/app-deleted':
                return 'O banco de dados não foi localizado.';
            case 'auth/expired-action-code':
                return 'O código da ação o ou link expirou.';
            case 'auth/invalid-action-code':
                return 'O código da ação é inválido. Isso pode acontecer se o código estiver malformado ou já tiver sido usado.';
            case 'auth/user-disabled':
                return 'O usuário correspondente à credencial fornecida foi desativado.';
            case 'auth/user-not-found':
                return 'O usuário não correponde à nenhuma credencial.';
            case 'auth/weak-password':
                return 'A senha é muito fraca.';
            case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
                return 'Já existi uma conta com o endereço de email fornecido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
                return 'O endereço de e-mail não é válido.';
            case 'auth/operation-not-allowed':
                return 'O tipo de conta correspondente à esta credencial, ainda não encontra-se ativada.';
            case 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential':
                return 'E-mail já associado a outra conta.';
            case 'auth/auth-domain-config-required':
                return 'A configuração para autenticação não foi fornecida.';
            case 'auth/credential-already-in-use':
                return 'Já existe uma conta para esta credencial.';
            case 'auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment':
                return 'Esta operação não é suportada no ambiente que está sendo executada. Verifique se deve ser http ou https.';
            case 'auth/timeout':
                return 'Excedido o tempo de resposta. O domínio pode não estar autorizado para realizar operações.';
            case 'auth/missing-android-pkg-name':
                return 'Deve ser fornecido um nome de pacote para instalação do aplicativo Android.';
            case 'auth/missing-continue-uri':
                return 'A próxima URL deve ser fornecida na solicitação.';
            case 'auth/missing-ios-bundle-id':
                return 'Deve ser fornecido um nome de pacote para instalação do aplicativo iOS.';
            case 'auth/invalid-continue-uri':
                return 'A próxima URL fornecida na solicitação é inválida.';
            case 'auth/unauthorized-continue-uri':
                return 'O domínio da próxima URL não está na lista de autorizações.';
            case 'auth/invalid-dynamic-link-domain':
                return 'O domínio de link dinâmico fornecido, não está autorizado ou configurado no projeto atual.';
            case 'auth/argument-error':
                return 'Verifique a configuração de link para o aplicativo.';
            case 'auth/invalid-persistence-type':
                return 'O tipo especificado para a persistência dos dados é inválido.';
            case 'auth/unsupported-persistence-type':
                return 'O ambiente atual não suportar o tipo especificado para persistência dos dados.';
            case 'auth/invalid-credential':
                return 'A credencial expirou ou está mal formada.';
            case 'auth/wrong-password':
                return 'Senha incorreta.';
            case 'auth/invalid-verification-code':
                return 'O código de verificação da credencial não é válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-verification-id':
                return 'O ID de verificação da credencial não é válido.';
            case 'auth/custom-token-mismatch':
                return 'O token está diferente do padrão solicitado.';
            case 'auth/invalid-custom-token':
                return 'O token fornecido não é válido.';
            case 'auth/captcha-check-failed':
                return 'O token de resposta do reCAPTCHA não é válido, expirou ou o domínio não é permitido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-phone-number':
                return 'O número de telefone está em um formato inválido (padrão E.164).';
            case 'auth/missing-phone-number':
                return 'O número de telefone é requerido.';
            case 'auth/quota-exceeded':
                return 'A cota de SMS foi excedida.';
            case 'auth/cancelled-popup-request':
                return 'Somente uma solicitação de janela pop-up é permitida de uma só vez.';
            case 'auth/popup-blocked':
                return 'A janela pop-up foi bloqueado pelo navegador.';
            case 'auth/popup-closed-by-user':
                return 'A janela pop-up foi fechada pelo usuário sem concluir o login no provedor.';
            case 'auth/unauthorized-domain':
                return 'O domínio do aplicativo não está autorizado para realizar operações.';
            case 'auth/invalid-user-token':
                return 'O usuário atual não foi identificado.';
            case 'auth/user-token-expired':
                return 'O token do usuário atual expirou.';
            case 'auth/null-user':
                return 'O usuário atual é nulo.';
            case 'auth/app-not-authorized':
                return 'Aplicação não autorizada para autenticar com a chave informada.';
            case 'auth/invalid-api-key':
                return 'A chave da API fornecida é inválida.';
            case 'auth/network-request-failed':
                return 'Falha de conexão com a rede.';
            case 'auth/requires-recent-login':
                return 'O último horário de acesso do usuário não atende ao limite de segurança.';
            case 'auth/too-many-requests':
                return 'As solicitações foram bloqueadas devido a atividades incomuns. Tente novamente depois que algum tempo.';
            case 'auth/web-storage-unsupported':
                return 'O navegador não suporta armazenamento ou se o usuário desativou este recurso.';
            case 'auth/invalid-claims':
                return 'Os atributos de cadastro personalizado são inválidos.';
            case 'auth/claims-too-large':
                return 'O tamanho da requisição excede o tamanho máximo permitido de 1 Megabyte.';
            case 'auth/id-token-expired':
                return 'O token informado expirou.';
            case 'auth/id-token-revoked':
                return 'O token informado perdeu a validade.';
            case 'auth/invalid-argument':
                return 'Um argumento inválido foi fornecido a um método.';
            case 'auth/invalid-creation-time':
                return 'O horário da criação precisa ser uma data UTC válida.';
            case 'auth/invalid-disabled-field':
                return 'A propriedade para usuário desabilitado é inválida.';
            case 'auth/invalid-display-name':
                return 'O nome do usuário é inválido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-email-verified':
                return 'O e-mail é inválido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-hash-algorithm':
                return 'O algoritmo de HASH não é uma criptografia compatível.';
            case 'auth/invalid-hash-block-size':
                return 'O tamanho do bloco de HASH não é válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-hash-derived-key-length':
                return 'O tamanho da chave derivada do HASH não é válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-hash-key':
                return 'A chave de HASH precisa ter um buffer de byte válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-hash-memory-cost':
                return 'O custo da memória HASH não é válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-hash-parallelization':
                return 'O carregamento em paralelo do HASH não é válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-hash-rounds':
                return 'O arredondamento de HASH não é válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-hash-salt-separator':
                return 'O campo do separador de SALT do algoritmo de geração de HASH precisa ser um buffer de byte válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-id-token':
                return 'O código do token informado não é válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-last-sign-in-time':
                return 'O último horário de login precisa ser uma data UTC válida.';
            case 'auth/invalid-page-token':
                return 'A próxima URL fornecida na solicitação é inválida.';
            case 'auth/invalid-password':
                return 'A senha é inválida, precisa ter pelo menos 6 caracteres.';
            case 'auth/invalid-password-hash':
                return 'O HASH da senha não é válida.';
            case 'auth/invalid-password-salt':
                return 'O SALT da senha não é válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-photo-url':
                return 'A URL da foto de usuário é inválido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-provider-id':
                return 'O identificador de provedor não é compatível.';
            case 'auth/invalid-session-cookie-duration':
                return 'A duração do COOKIE da sessão precisa ser um número válido em milissegundos, entre 5 minutos e 2 semanas.';
            case 'auth/invalid-uid':
                return 'O identificador fornecido deve ter no máximo 128 caracteres.';
            case 'auth/invalid-user-import':
                return 'O registro do usuário a ser importado não é válido.';
            case 'auth/invalid-provider-data':
                return 'O provedor de dados não é válido.';
            case 'auth/maximum-user-count-exceeded':
                return 'O número máximo permitido de usuários a serem importados foi excedido.';
            case 'auth/missing-hash-algorithm':
                return 'É necessário fornecer o algoritmo de geração de HASH e seus parâmetros para importar usuários.';
            case 'auth/missing-uid':
                return 'Um identificador é necessário para a operação atual.';
            case 'auth/reserved-claims':
                return 'Uma ou mais propriedades personalizadas fornecidas usaram palavras reservadas.';
            case 'auth/session-cookie-revoked':
                return 'O COOKIE da sessão perdeu a validade.';
            case 'auth/uid-alread-exists':
                return 'O indentificador fornecido já está em uso.';
            case 'auth/email-already-exists':
                return 'O e-mail fornecido já está em uso.';
            case 'auth/phone-number-already-exists':
                return 'O telefone fornecido já está em uso.';
            case 'auth/project-not-found':
                return 'Nenhum projeto foi encontrado.';
            case 'auth/insufficient-permission':
                return 'A credencial utilizada não tem permissão para acessar o recurso solicitado.';
            case 'auth/internal-error':
                return 'O servidor de autenticação encontrou um erro inesperado ao tentar processar a solicitação.';
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

IOS Auth errors are:

Name:  Hash;  RawValue(code):

```
 - AccountExistsWithDifferentCredential: 10; 17012
 - InvalidEmail: 6; 17008
 - NetworkError: 15; 17020
 - UserDisabled: 3; 17005
 - UserMismatch: 18; 17024
 - UserNotFound: 9; 17011
 - WeakPassword: 20; 17026
 - InternalError: 23; 17999
 - InvalidAPIKey: 17; 17023
 - KeychainError: 22; 17995
 - WrongPassword: 7; 17009
 - NoSuchProvider: 13; 17016
 - TooManyRequests: 8; 17010
 - AppNotAuthorized: 21; 17028
 - InvalidUserToken: 14; 17017
 - UserTokenExpired: 16; 17021
 - EmailAlreadyInUse: 5; 17007
 - InvalidCredential: 2; 17004
 - InvalidCustomToken: 0; 17000
 - CustomTokenMismatch: 1; 17002
 - OperationNotAllowed: 4; 17006
 - RequiresRecentLogin: 11; 17014
 - ProviderAlreadyLinked: 12; 17015
 - CredentialAlreadyInUse: 19; 17025
```

Comment: Where did you find these? I need more for other services like Firestore etc.

Comment: I really don't remember.....I suspect I went source diving but not sure.
Oh, possibly from one of their demo projects....