# How can I change the validator state from outside it's function

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I created a view model for sign up and in there are my validators.

```
String? emailValidator(String? s) {
  if(s == null || s.isEmpty || s.isWhiteSpace()){
    return "Email is required";
  }

  if(!s.isValidEmail()){
    return "Invalid email address";
  }

  return null;
}
```

When I create an account I call createUserWithEmailAndPassword but when the user already exists this throws an exception.

```
onPressed: () {                  
  final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();

  assert(isValid == viewModel.isValid(),
    "The view model and form must agree on whether the form is valid");

  if(isValid && viewModel.isValid()){
    try{
      FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: viewModel.email!, password: viewModel.password!);
    }catch{
      // what should I do here?
    }
  }
},
```

Now I want to catch it and update my validator so that i can display an error like "email address already in use". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bool

```
bool emailExists = false;
```

```
String? emailValidator(String? s) {
  if(s == null || s.isEmpty || s.isWhiteSpace()){
    return "Email is required";
  }

  if(!s.isValidEmail()){
    return "Invalid email address";
  }
  if(emailExists) return "Registered Email Exists";
  return null;
}
```

and on button press in catch you can update the bool and validate again

```
onPressed: () {                  
  final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();

  assert(isValid == viewModel.isValid(),
    "The view model and form must agree on whether the form is valid");

  if(isValid && viewModel.isValid()){
    try{
      FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: viewModel.email!, password: viewModel.password!);
    }catch{
      emailExists = true;
     formKey.currentState!.validate();
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Yes I thought of this as well but just wondered if there was a cleaner option since I don't like to use too many flags.

Comment: Textfield also has an error text. If you update it and set state it will show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Since you to use `try`/`catch`, the syntax for handling exception is:

```
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: "sparky@firebaseexample.com",
    password: "CorrectHorseBatteryStaple"
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  print("Caught FirebaseAuthException");
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(content: Text(e.code+'\n\n\n'+e.message!))
  );                            
} catch (e) {
  print("Caught other error");
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString()))
  );                            
}
```

You likely only need the first `catch` block which handles [`FirebaseAuthException`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/FirebaseAuthException-class.html)s, and in there you can use `e.code` to determine the actual error code from Firebase. For the actual codes, see [what are the error codes for Flutter Firebase Auth Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67617502/what-are-the-error-codes-for-flutter-firebase-auth-exception)

We did an episode of the Flutter Boring Show on this topic a while ago, so I recommend checking that out: [Firebase Authentication in Flutter (The Boring Flutter Development Show, Ep. 55)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gz0x77Hd1GE), also see the [final code](https://gist.github.com/puf/e958143be44d39d1203abfbc70082d7d) of what we created there.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want the error to show up as a Snackbar but as an error below my TextFormField

Comment: The code in my answer shows how to catch the error. You can do with it what you want afterwards.