# SnackBar is not displying

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

So, I have created one snackbar widget in different dart file and I'm calling it in different dart file with context and text message. but when I'm getting error at that time snackbar is not showing on screen.

This is Separate dart file that contains Snackbar widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/globals.dart' as globals;

class ErrorAlert{

  showAlert(context, message) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: globals.mainColor,
        content: Text(message),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Dismiss',
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
          },
        ),
      )

    );
  }

}
```

Here the Code from where I'm calling it (in catch part if condition):

```
signInWithEmailIdAndPassword(email,password, context) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user!;
      // checkUser = user; //returns UserID
      if(result != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()));
      }
    }
    catch(signError) {
      if(signError is PlatformException) {
        if(signError.code == 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD') {
          ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'Wrong Password!');
        } else if(signError.code == 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL') {
          ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'Invalid Email ID!');
        } else if(signError.code == 'ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL') {
          ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'Account is already exists with different credentials!');
        } else if(signError.code == 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND') {
          ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'User not found!');
        }
        print(signError);
      }
    }
    // return checkUser;
  }
```

This is the debug message that is showing in console:

```
E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(32567): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - The email address is badly formatted.
```

Comment: Are you certain that the `showAlert` is being called?

Comment: It seems your else if does not cover the case you are facing, try adding an `else { ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'Error Catched'); } `

Comment: @SujanGainju `showAlert` is not being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you are trying to catch is not in the right `if` nesting.
At the moment you are first trying to check if it is a `PlatformException` whereas Firebase is throwing `FirebaseAuthException`

You should try the following:

```
signInWithEmailIdAndPassword(email,password, context) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user!;
      // checkUser = user; //returns UserID
      if(result != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()));
      }
    }
    catch(signError) {
      if(signError is PlatformException) {
        // DO STUFF
       
      }
      if (signError is FirebaseAuthException) {
         if(signError.code == 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD') {
          ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'Wrong Password!');
        } else if(signError.code == 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL') {
          ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'Invalid Email ID!');
        } else if(signError.code == 'ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL') {
          ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'Account is already exists with different credentials!');
        } else if(signError.code == 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND') {
          ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'User not found!');
        } else {
          ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'Something went wrong!');
        }
      }
    }
    // return checkUser;
  }
```

Also always check all the cases here you had no else status.

Additionally make sure to have the correct return codes for Firebase as if I remember correctly the invalid email code is `invalid-email` but you may already have constant that covers it.

Comment: can you share updated list of exception code for this?

Comment: you have all the details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67617502/what-are-the-error-codes-for-flutter-firebase-auth-exception

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as correct if it helped you :) @DP_

Answer (score 0):

So for this is the problem with the context actually for better understanding you can refer this thread
[Can someone explain to me what the Builder Class does in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088889/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-the-builder-class-does-in-flutter)

And to resolve your issue you can do it like this.

```
new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                ErrorAlert().showAlert(context, 'Wrong Password!');
              },
              child: const Text('click'));
        })
```